# Django Multiple Annotations with HAVING, COUNT and AVG

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Trying to display TOP 10 business popularity list based on AVG. Everything works but I'm trying to add additional conditions such as only include businesses HAVING at least 10 votes.

This works for the AVG with all results:

```
Feedvote.objects.filter(site_id=settings.SITE_ID).annotate(
                        voteavg=Avg('feedvote')).order_by('-voteavg')[:10]
```

Here trying to add HAVING condition for at least 10 votes:

Edit: When I run this code below I get nothing, no errors, no values.

```
Feedvote.objects.filter(city=settings.SITE_ID).annotate(
                       voteavg=Avg('feedvote')).annotate(
                       count_status=Count('business')).filter(
                       count_status__gt=10).order_by('-voteavg')[:10]
```

Comment: Please describe the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: When I run the code above with the `COUNT` I get nothing, no errors, no values, nothing.

Comment: If you need "at least 10" then you should use "__gte" instead of "__gt"

Comment: @shellbye You are correct, however that does not solve the issue of not having any results when the __gte is anything larger than 1. Somehow it does not group the results by the business ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's generating SQL that doesn't return any data. This is because the second annotate call is being calculated based on the results of the first. You could try using to combine them to avoid this.

```
Feedvote.objects.filter(city=settings.SITE_ID).annotate(
    voteavg=Avg('feedvote'),
    count_status=Count('business', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Same as the above, I get nothing unless the `count_status__gt` is `0`. Running few test, I'm getting results that are not grouped by the business ID showing everything count = 1. For some reason the query is not grouping the results by the business ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put all annotate together:

```
Feedvote.objects.filter(site_id=settings.SITE_ID).annotate(voteavg=Avg('feedvote'),count_status=Count('business')).filter(count_status__gte=10).order_by('-voteavg')[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that replied! I got it all up and running. The issue was that Django wanted to query the **`Business`** table based on the `Feedvote` table values. In SQL I would query the `Feedvote` table with the `Business` table as `JOIN`. Django wanted otherwise.

```
Business.objects.filter(city_id=settings.SITE_ID)
                .annotate(count_status=Count('feedvotes__business'))
                .filter(count_status__gte=10)
                .annotate(voteavg=Avg('feedvotes__feedvote'))
                .order_by('-voteavg')[:10]
```